# Using small angle approximation to turn x(t) and y(t) to the usual projectile kinematic equation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, physics

Given the horizontal and vertical position-time functions:
\begin{align*}
        x(t) &= \frac{v_0\cos\ \theta\sin\ \omega t}{\omega}\\
        y(t) &= \dfrac{v_0\sin\ \theta\sin(\omega t)}{\omega} + \frac{mg}{k} \cos(\omega t) - \frac{mg}{k}
\end{align*}

Show that both functions reduce to usual projectile kinematic equations for very small $\omega$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $$\sin x\approx x\\\cos x\approx 1-\frac12x^2$$
So $$\frac{\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}\approx t$$and $$\cos(\omega t)-1\approx-\frac12(\omega t)^2$$

Comment: I don't think I completely understood your answer. Aren't we supposed to turn $\dfrac{v_0cos\ \theta}{\omega}sin\ \omega t$ to $v_0cos\ \theta (t)$ and the $y(t)$ function to $v_0sin\ \theta(t) \pm \dfrac{1}{2}gt^2$? These are the usual projectile kinematic equations right?

Comment: Yes. And you can see that the first equation becomes $x(t)=(v_0\cos\theta) t$. In the second equation, the middle term becomes $(v_0\sin\theta)t$. And the first and third will become $-\frac12\frac{mg\omega^2}k t^2$. Then $\frac{mg\omega^2}k$ has the role of the acceleration

Comment: It was not clear from the context, but I think $\omega^2=k/m$, so the acceleration than is just $g$

Comment: I see. Everything makes sense now. Thank you.

Comment: How did we get $\dfrac{sin(\omega t)}{\omega} \approx t$?

Comment: $\sin(\omega t)\approx \omega t$. Just divide both sides by $\omega$